# Adding props to specific columns in MUI datatables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am working with MUI datatables (https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables
) in React and want to pass column props to specific columns

MUI data tables accepts column props (options) in the following way:

```
const columns = [
 {
  name: "name",
  label: "Name",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: true,
  }
 },
 {
  name: "company",
  label: "Company",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
  }
 },
 {
  name: "city",
  label: "City",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
  }
 },
 {
  name: "state",
  label: "State",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
  }
 },
];

const data = [
 { name: "Joe James", company: "Test Corp", city: "Yonkers", state: "NY" },
 { name: "John Walsh", company: "Test Corp", city: "Hartford", state: "CT" },
 { name: "Bob Herm", company: "Test Corp", city: "Tampa", state: "FL" },
 { name: "James Houston", company: "Test Corp", city: "Dallas", state: "TX" },
];

const options = {
  filterType: 'checkbox',
};

<MUIDataTable
  title={"Employee List"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={options}
/>
```

However I do not want to specifically state each column entry within the project as I am retrieving the data through an API call.

How could I pass specific column props to certain columns?

i.e. Pass `options: {display: false}` to only the columns "City" and "State"?

Comment: Yes. You can pass `options: {display: false}`. More options available at https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#column-options

Comment: Yes, but I am referring to identifying specific columns within an object and passing props to those columns